# Change NordVPN tun interface name

Tags: vpn, docker, tunnel

I want to run `NordVPN` in multiple docker containers. When using the `host` network the `NordVPN` client creates and uses a `tun0` device. However, when running a second container, it is trying to create and use another `tun0` device, which, obviously, does not work.

How can I tell the second container to use a different device?